# Getting InvalidAuthenticationToken from Microsoft Graph when trying to read mails

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to read mails via graph.microsoft but I am getting the error at the bottom. If I use SMTP and Pop it's, working, but the challenge is that I can’t delete the mails after processing but with Office 365 API I can. How can i fix it?

**my Code**

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certs = store
            .Certificates
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "VaultWear lcbs Cert", false);
        var clientCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate("My Client_id", certs[0]);
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my Tennant_id}/oauth2/v1.0/token");
        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("My Client_id ", clientCertificate).Result;//
        string tokenKey = result.AccessToken.ToString();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenKey);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages");

        string retResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

**Error**

> {   "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
>       "message": "Access token validation failure.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "6337285e-1503-4af8-9724-1eeecb9973a4",
>         "date": "2018-03-18T23:25:38"
>       }   } }

Comment: I'm not sure about the auth issue, but the call to Microsoft Graph should have a version of v1.0 or beta, not v2.0. Versioning documented at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/versioning_and_support#versions